# Unmatched app urls when trying to publish to Chrome Store

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting the following error when I try to publish:

This hosted web app has one or more app urls not owned by the developer.
The web_url of this hosted web app is not owned by the developer.

I am getting the green warning box as described in:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1520

However, I'm hitting the refresh button and no joy in the solving the problem.  I've published a lot of apps scripts in the past and never had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your url with the Google webmaster tools program and they will give you code to fix this. In case you have already done that, just go and verify again. It happened to me as well and I had to verify the site again. It works!